# Lodash - sort objects in object ( desc and asc)

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, object, lodash

How to sort object of objects asc and desc using Lodash?

For example i want to sort it by 'r' or 'd'.

This is how my object looks like:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean by placing objects to different keys in a sorted order..? If so you can do this simply by pure JS. one way is to move them to an array and sort there and then copy back to the obj in sorted order.. or another way is add a length property to your master object with a value of total number of object elements and then do Array.prototype.sort.call(obj,callback)

Comment: Per the JavaScript spec, the properties of an object have no order.  There is no "first" or "last" property; they cannot be sorted. Regardless of the order you assign them (or the order they appear in the console), you are not guaranteed to get them back in any particular order when enumerating them. If you need an ordered data structure, use an Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place internal objects in array and use function [sortBy()](https://lodash.com/docs#sortBy)

```
var users = [
 { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 48 },
 { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 },
 { 'user': 'fred',   'age': 40 },
 { 'user': 'barney', 'age': 34 }
];

_.sortBy(users, function(o) { return o.user; });
// → objects for [['barney', 36], ['barney', 34], ['fred', 48], ['fred', 40]]
console.log(users.reverse()); // desc order
```

Comment: I did it like this. i did  `_.sortBy(sortArray, function(o){return o.d;}); and it doesn't work. Objects are still sorted as they were at start.

Answer (score 1):

Pure JS is also very simple and you may do something like this;

```js
var   obj = {a:16, b:2, c:8, d:4, e:1},
    okeys = Object.keys(obj),
   sorted = {};
okeys.sort((p,c) => obj[p] <= obj[c]).forEach((p,i) => sorted[okeys[i]] = obj[p]);
document.write('<pre> ' + JSON.stringify(sorted, 0, 2) + '</pre>');
```

I am sorting object properties according to their numerical values. Their values could be objects and you could sort according to these objects property values as well. But i can not comment on what could be a sensible reason behind doing all this.