# javascript messes array order when transforming to js object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I got this subarray inside my array:

```
["sizes"] array(3) {
["6.5"] "yes"
[7] "no"
["7.5"] "yes"
}
```

I send this data as json along something else to a script that transforms it to js object:

```
var sizes = obj.items[i].sizes;
```

what happens then is that the resulting object has messed order and I get something like this:

```
Object {7: "no", 6.5: "yes", 7.5: "yes"}
```

instead of:

```
Object {6.5: "yes", 7: "no", 7.5: "yes"}
```

is there a way to force the script to preserve the original order?

Comment: Use array. Array is ordered collection. Object is not.

Comment: Show us the code that transforms it to object then we can tell you how to transform it to array instead.

Comment: You can easily sort object keys afterwards. I did something similar to this in http://stackoverflow.com/a/36645727/4543207

Comment: I used the array then looped as key value as in this example http://www.electrictoolbox.com/loop-key-value-pairs-associative-array-javascript/ but it still gives messed data.

Answer (score 0):

ES6 specifies object key order, to a point, as written about here:

http://www.2ality.com/2015/10/property-traversal-order-es6.html

If you are using ES3 or ES5 -- or you don't like the ES6 order, then you would best be served by using an ES6 MAP polyfill.

According to the [ES6 Map Specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) the keys are returned by insertion order.

[A shim to look at](https://github.com/WebReflection/es6-collections)

Comment: I don't know what ES version it's involved but since I have non integer keys I used an array instead of and obj and it still messes the data.

Comment: Then look at the Map shim I posted.

Comment: I found an easier way. I concatenated my $key to ." " (white space) in the php side. That transformed all the keys in strings rather than having mixed ints and strings and now the iteration preserves order as there are no more keys that are ints. I tried to cast the int to string in the php side with all the methods ( (string)$key .. $key = "$key" .. strval($key) ) to no avail, the int remained int in the resulting array.